# Method to secure these two parts, with constraints

Tags: aluminum, metalwork

How should I complete this task?

2 aluminium discs, around 55mm diam x 20mm high.
The top disc must;

1. be able to rotate 360deg w.r.t the bottom disc
2. once in desired rotational position, be secured to the bottom disc
3. Steps 1 and 2 repeatable, so only temporarily secured ie nothing permanent
4. the top disc's top surface can't be used for screws etc. It must remain smooth.
5. once secured the top will be used to rotate the pair. Will rotate in both directions, with no bias in a particular direction. Just by hand, no great forces involved. Think of it as a fancy dial/knob

Also;

6. the bottom of the bottom disc is not accessible. As the top also isn't, any screws etc will have to be in the side/s where the knurling is.
7. the knurling on the 2 halves won't line up - arbitrary rotational positioning of the top is critical
   [image]

Comment: Expanding mandrel?